# Задача Minimum of two. Проблема с циклом

Tags: java

Есть 20 пар чисел через пробел. Надо найти минимум в каждой паре. В результате надо вернуть строку, состоящую из минимальных чисел в паре.
В моей реализации теряется последняя пара чисел

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNext()){
           int  a  = scanner.nextInt();
           int  b = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print(Math.min(a,b)+" ");

        }

    }
}
```

Пробовал и через for, думаю тут проблема в конструкции внутри цикла.

Пример входных данных

```
-3504043 3516431
-2242539 3864272
5304938 217763
```

Пример ответа :

```
-3504043 -2242539 217763
```

Comment: что значит "съедает"?

Comment: Выводит все минимальные числа, кроме последней, последнюю игнорит.

Comment: Дополните вопрос примером исходных данных и результатом. Думаю вмето 20 пар хватит 4х, результат должен быть тем же самым

Comment: блин, числа в примере стоят в столбик, тут не получается их так поставить http://prntscr.com/hwe4hv

Comment: попробуй do {} while()

Comment: У вас все корректно работает. Просто нажмите еще раз энтер после ввода последней пары. Единственное, что при таком вводе результат вы возвращаете не строкой, а после каждого чтения входных данных

Comment: а я ввожу не по парам, а сразу весь список копирую и вставляю.и даже энтер не успеваю нажать сразу выводятся минимальные числа на консоль. На то и расчет, после каждого чтения, он вычисляет, и пишет число на консоль через пробел

Comment: кроме последней пары. После вывода, нажмите еще раз enter и выведется результат сравнения последней пары

Comment: А все, понял, гениально просто. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя цикл считывает по условию, что есть чего считывать. Замени while на do..while. Будет работать

Answer (score 1):

Все что требовалось, это просто нажать enter после ввода чисел.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/226800)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Вот это да. А где такой шаблон в очереди проверок?

Comment: @0xdb Сам удивлен - вчера был :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, а где ты тут "спасибо" увидел? Вроде нормальный ответ и от других отличается.

Comment: @Qwertiy А ты очередь правок посмотри и время ответов :)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в условии цикла while - он будет работать пока есть следующие цифры, а последняя пара именно из за условия не выводиться. Вот рабочий вариант:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            int a = scanner.nextInt();
            int b = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(Math.min(a,b));
        }
    }
}
```